# the_date() not working

Tags: php, query, mysql, date

I am using wordpress 3.2 and I did a query post like this:

```
<?php query_posts("posts_per_page=1post=type&page=post_parent=10");?>
```

Then I try to echo out the date of this post I queried like this.

```
<?php echo the_date(); ?>
```

It gives me the title of the post and the excerpt and the permalink but no date. What do you think the problem is. I'm sure it's something quite embarrassing.

Here is the code in my template file for the video page:

```
    <?php query_posts("posts_per_page=1post=type&page=post_parent=10");?>
    <h2>Recent Video</h2>
    <h3 class="date"><?php echo the_date(); ?></h3>
    <p><strong><?php echo the_title(); ?></strong><?php echo the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    <p><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" class="more2">Watch Now</a></p>
```

Here I try to put the query in a loop:

```
<?php query_posts("posts_per_page=1post=type&page=post_parent=10");?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h2>Recent Video</h2>
<h3 class="date"><?php echo the_date(); ?></h3>
<p><strong><?php echo the_title(); ?></strong><?php echo the_excerpt(); ?></p>
<p><a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" class="more2">Watch Now</a></p>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

the_date() did not work but the the_title() and other functions worked. By the way this changed my query to the_post() which is not what I'm wanting. I want to query the latest video like I did above the loop.

By the way I used the_date function earlier in the page and it worked. Could that be the problem? Here is it before the code that I had a problem with.

```
<div id="col75" class="firstcol">
    <iframe id="video" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=<?php print get_post_meta($post->ID,"playlist_id", true); ?>" width='560' height='350' frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <div id="col25">
        <h2><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,"speaker", true); ?></h2>
        <h3 class="date"><?php echo the_date(); ?></h3>
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

See this [special note about using the `the_date'](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date)

> SPECIAL NOTE: When there are multiple posts on a page published under
>   the SAME DAY, the_date() only displays the date for the first post
>   (that is, the first instance of the_date()). To repeat the date for
>   posts published under the same day, you should use the Template Tag
>   the_time() or get_the_date() (since 3.0) with a date-specific format
>   string. Use  to add the
>   date set in the admin interface.

1. You are using `query_posts` which screws up the globals
2. You are echoing a function that already prints to the browser

   - You are actually doing that for all your template tags.
   - Change `echo the_date();` to: `echo get_the_date('F j, Y');`
   - Remove the echo from  your template tags that already print to the browser or use the alternate functions that return the value.
3. Use a new [`WP_Query`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts) or `get_posts` instead of [`query_posts`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)
4. Read the Codex.  It tells you how to use all these functions and is very helpful :)

Comment: get_the_date() fixed my problem but now my sidebar.php get_the_date() is broken.

Comment: Another victim of `query_posts`

Comment: Okay it's working now but I had to used the echo tags. That is why it didn't work in my sidebar.php.

Answer (score 21):

[`the_date()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date) prints the date only if the same date was *not printed before*.
No, that's not consistent with other similar functions. But that’s [how it worked in WordPress’ ancestor **b2/cafelog**](http://cafelog.com/readme.html#templates), and backwards compatibility always trumps logic … :)

To print the date always use `get_the_date()`

```
<?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo mysql2date( get_option( 'date_format' ), $post->post_date); ?>
```

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO. Now my side bar get_the_date is broken. What happen there?

Comment: See Cris_O's answer and [don't use `query_posts()`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/73). :)

Comment: **Your Using query_posts** which is breaking your globals.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is meant to be run within the `while( have_posts() )` conditional:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_date();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;
```

Comment: How do I just say the date of the post? That's all I want to do? I only queried one post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the loop for certain functions to work. All of these functions list, on their codex page, that they will not function properly outside of the loop.

Comment: No that doesn't work I posted the code of what I did in the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This won't show date in all cases
the_date( 'F d, Y' );

// This will show date in all cases
the_time( 'F d, Y' );
```