# WordPress | Date not always appear

Tags: wp-query, loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WordPress the_date() not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52489/wordpress-the-date-not-working)

I try to create a theme. In that theme I have create a custom post type and I quering the WordPress by using the wp_query to get the posts from that post type with the code that following :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         =>  'portfolio',
    'posts_per_page'    =>  18
);

$projects = new WP_Query($args);

while($projects->have_posts())
{
    $projects->the_post();
?>
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<span><?php the_date(); ?></span>
<?php
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

the problem is, that while I get the title for all of my posts, I do not get the date for all of my posts. Some posts have the date, other they don't

Any idea for that issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `get_the_date()` instead, here's note from `the_date()` codex [page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date) regarding the issue:

> When there are multiple posts on a page published under the SAME DAY,
>   the_date() only displays the date for the first post (that is, the
>   first instance of the_date()). To repeat the date for posts published
>   under the same day, you should use the Template Tag the_time() or
>   get_the_date() (since 3.0) with a date-specific format string.